# Conditional string replace

Tags: php, xml, regex, character-encoding, xml-parsing

I have  a funcion which is somthing like this :

```
function replaceXMLEntities($subject) {
 $subject = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $subject);
 $subject = str_replace("'", "&apos;", $subject);
 $subject = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $subject);
 $subject = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $subject);
 $subject = str_replace("\"", "&quot;", $subject);

 return $subject;
}
```

This function is used to convert strings to a safe string for xmpl encoding.

But i have a problem in which casses some xmpl data ges encoded 2 times, like

```
&amp;
```

as imput gets to

```
&&amp;
```

Just like in here when you enter the text without code quote :)

I need  a regex which could distinguish between & and & somthing like

```
if not &amp then do & -> &amp; conversion else dont touch it.
```

Any idea how i could achive such regex? I could go and make a funciton but in this case a regex is clearly a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$subject = preg_replace('#(?!&amp;)&#', '&amp;', $subject);`

Though using `htmlspecialchars()` might be easier...

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve the same without a regular expression by replacing all `&amp`s with `&` first:

```
$subject = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $subject);
```

Comment: Simple but briliant thy :3

Answer (score 0):

Hardcore way:

```
preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-z0-9]+;)/', '&amp;', '&amp; & &lt; &gt;');
```

Easy and right way is using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple using [**`preg_replace()`**](http://php.net/preg-replace)<sup>**regex**</sup>:
`$subject = preg_replace('&(?!amp;)', '', $subject);`

`&`: match `&`                                                `(?!amp;)`: Negative lookahead, check if there is no `amp;`

We'll still use [**`str_replace()`**](http://php.net/str-replace) for the other characters, but note that it supports several inputs/replacements, so our final code will be:

```
function replaceXMLEntities($subject){
    $subject = preg_replace('&(?!amp;)', '', $subject);
    $subject = str_replace(array("'", '<', '>', '"'), array('&apos;', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;'), $subject);

    return $subject;
}
```

You could also use a tricky way, first replace all `&amp;` with `&` and then replace all `&` with `&amp;`:

```
function replaceXMLEntities($subject){
    return str_replace(array('&amp;', '&', "'", '<', '>', '"'), array('&', '&amp;', '&apos;', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;'), $subject);
}
```